# Datetimeoffset does not give the correct format

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I have a variable start that holds the value "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000-05:00". Then I set another variable end to DateTimeOffset.Now but when I hover over it, it will tell me "9/1/2021 9:15:10 AM -05:00". I am wanting to have the variable end to have the same formatting as start does. Is there a way to have the formatting to display as it shows for variable start? I can't seem to find the answer I am looking for on the internet. Any pointers would be great.

```
var start = "2020-07-01T00:00:00.000-05:00"
var end = DateTimeOffset.Now
```

Comment: "I am wanting to have the variable end to have the same formatting as start does" - this is like saying "I want my `int` variable to be in hex rather than decimal". A `DateTimeOffset` doesn't have a format. If you just call `ToString()`, it will use the culture-default format. It's important to differentiate between "the data within the object" and "the default text representation of that data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTimeOffset` has [`ToString()` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_DateTimeOffset_ToString_System_String_) which accept format. You can try either one of the [standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or build a [custom one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

```cs
Console.WriteLine(DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffK")); // exmaple output: 2021-09-01T16:55:13.815+02:00
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! :)